# How to use Load Balancers in GCP to point to backend port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have `3` servers running on `GCP`.

So each server exposes a port `2379` that I can use to access as below:

`<server-ip>`:2379

**eg:**

10.128.15.215:2379

10.128.15.216:2379

10.128.15.217:2379

But, since I need to change ip address every time, I created a unmanaged instance group and put all the three servers in a one group.

Now I need to create a Load Balancer and I need to point that load balancer to that unmanaged instance group **and importantly i need to troute the traffic coming to load balancer to that 2379 port**

So it would look like below:

Imagine IP address of the load balancer is `10.128.15.220`,

So when I hit `10.128.15.220:2379` it should route traffic to those 3 servers and at their `2379` ports.

So traffic route will be like below:

```
10.128.15.220:2379 ----> LOAD BALANCER ----> Sends traffic at 2379 port of `3` servers
```

How can I do this, what **type** of Load balancer I can use, Are there any **simple** tutorials on doing this?

Comment: Ok, let's go 1 step further. I understood that when 1 request comes into the Load Balancer, you would like to duplicate it and to send the data to the 3 servers. If that is correct, let me know what can you expect from the Load Balancer to provide a response to the request? Should it wait all the response or only one? Should it aggregate the internal server response or pick only one?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no no nooo, nothing complex, just route the traffic coming to load balancer to any server's port `2379`

Comment: Ok, to any!! Like in round robin right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup an internal load balancer.
Try this Quicklab from Google is a good reference: [Create a load balancer](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/1250?parent=catalog).

(You will need a qwicklabs account. When you set up one, you have Google will send you enough free credits to do the lab on their systems)

Comment: But internal TCP/UDP load balancers only point the traffic to port `80` where I need to point it to port `2379`

Comment: *@Jananath Jayarathna* Have you checked the documentation [Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal) section [Forwarding rules and port specifications](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal#all_ports)?

Comment: i read it but still didn't understand how to do that.

Comment: *@Jananath Jayarathna* could you just start following the documentation and update your question with your detailed steps, commands and outputs? It'll be helpful to understand what's you problem and how to help you.